# Regular expression : validate numbers greater than 0, with or without leading zeros

Tags: regex, digit

I need a regular expression that will match strings like T001, T1, T012, T150 ---- T999.

I made it like this : `[tT][0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]`, but obviously it will also match T0, T00 and T000, which I don't want to.

How can I force the last character to be 1 if the previous one or two are zeros ?

Comment: T150 is not ending with `1` either, why match?

Comment: `[tT][0-9]?[0-9]?[1-9]` ?

Comment: Basicaly, I want to validate Strings that start with t, followed by  numbers  greater than 0 which can be written in equivalent ways like this: 001 = 01 = 1   ; 15 = 015 . Thats why i was asking for a way to force the last digit to be 1 ONLY IF the previous two are zeros

Comment: So you want to get the strings, and make them to have at least 1 with padding zeros? Your requirements seem a bit vague.

Comment: I explained in my comment above. So yes, I want to validate numbers greater than 0 (so at least 1) which can have leading (padding) zeros or not. Modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy using a negative lookahead: `^[tT](?!0{1,3}$)[0-9]{1,3}$`

**Explanation**

```
^               # match begin of string
[tT]            # match t or T
(?!             # negative lookahead, check if there is no ...
    0{1,3}      # match 0, 00 or 000
    $           # match end of string
)               # end of lookahead
[0-9]{1,3}      # match a digit one or three times
$               # match end of string
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xM6sP7)

Comment: Works great! Thank you for the answer. I'm trying to learn how to build complex regular expressions and that site you gave is a great start:)

Comment: @darkdante You may start learning from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/). Also browsing some answers here on SO might give you more tips & tricks. Finally you might join the [regex chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex) for more *cool* things :)

Answer (score 3):

I would not use regexp for that.

```
<?php
function tValue($str) {
    if (intval(substr($str, 1)) !== 0) {
        // T value is greater than 0
        return $str;
    } else {
        // convert T<any number of 0> to T<any number-1 of 0>1
        return $str[ (strlen($str) - 1) ] = '1';
    }
 }

 // output: T150
 echo tValue('T150'), PHP_EOL;

 // output: T00001
 echo tValue('T00000'), PHP_EOL;

 // output: T1
 echo tValue('T0'), PHP_EOL;

 // output: T555
 echo tValue('T555'), PHP_EOL;
```

Codepad: http://codepad.org/hqZpo8K9

Comment: I thought it was possible with regular expressions too. It's easy to do it the "common" coding way:) Marked as answer though. Thank you.

Comment: I am sure there is RegExp way, but this is easier and faster, enjoy :-)